# Userform that uses a Combobox with SUMIFS to sum data that meets requirements

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently working on my first VBA code and am very new to VBA. I am trying to essentially make something that will add my values in column "F" together so long as the date in column "K" occurred in 2018. Column "K" is formatted as a date in my sheet and I am having trouble getting it to work between dates. I have tried a lot of different things to make it work but here is what I have right now.

```
Private Sub date_box_Change()
Dim STrange As Date, ENDrange As Date, date_value As Date

date_value = date_box
STrange = date_value
ENDrange = DateAdd("d", 365, date_value)

Me.production_amount = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(Sheet2.Range("F1:F152"), _
Sheet2.Range("K1:K152"), ">=" & "STrange", Sheet2.Range("K1:K152"), "<=" & "ENDrange")
End Sub

Private Sub Userform_Initialize()

Me.date_box.AddItem CDate("1/1/2017")
Me.date_box.AddItem CDate("1/1/2018")
Me.date_box.AddItem CDate("1/1/2019")
Me.date_box.AddItem CDate("1/1/2020")


End Sub
```

Like I said I am completely new to VBA any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Variables don't belong in quotes... `STrange` and `ENDrange` should not be in quotes in the line `Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(Sheet2.Range("F1:F152"), _
Sheet2.Range("K1:K152"), ">=" & "STrange", Sheet2.Range("K1:K152"), "<=" & "ENDrange")`.

Comment: Thank you! I have the date working now I need to find a way to make a string variable that checks if the text contains "type 1A" or "type 1B" and count them as the same string. Unfortunately I can't just use a wildcard here because some of them are labelled "kind 1A" and "kind 1B". But essentially I need it to be able to search column H and determine if the text contains the specified characters or not before including them in the total.